# Post request via soapclient

Tags: php, xml, soap

Currently i am communication to Soap Server via CURL. I am sending XML data to URL using specific Header, i want to replace curl with SoapClient Class but not sure how to do it.

Curl Code:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);                                                                      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);                                                                    
                                                                                                                $xml = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

Parameters:

Header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SoapAction: "http://www.mygemini.com/schemas/mygemini/GetAccountMovements"
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)
```

Body:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:myg="http://www.mygemini.com/schemas/mygemini" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"> 
  <soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security>
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
      <wsse:Username>USER</wsse:Username>
      <wsse:Password>PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
      <wsse:Nonce>1111</wsse:Nonce>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <myg:GetAccountMovementsRequestIo>
      <myg:accountMovementFilterIo>
        <myg:periodFrom>2015-01-01T00:00:00.000</myg:periodFrom>
      </myg:accountMovementFilterIo>
    </myg:GetAccountMovementsRequestIo>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry, not sure what you mean

Comment: _"i want to replace curl with SoapClient"_ - Have you actually tried doing that (written any code implementing the SoapClient-class) or are you asking us to just do it all for you?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i explored php.net manual , checked on google tried some examples but i can't seem to understand the logic or able to find good manual. in curl it is simple you set the header post the fields and done.